# python modifying a variable with a function

Tags: python, function, variables

I am trying to write a function for a basic python course that I am taking. We are at the point where we join as a group and make one program as a team. I have assigned each member to write their portion as a function in the hopes that I can just call each function to perform the overall program. It has been a while since I played in object programing and this is above the class requirements but I want to try and make this work.

I am having difficulty passing a variable into a function then retrieving the changed variable from the function.

I have tried reading on multiple sites and deep search on here but I am missing something and any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the first sample of code I tried

```
import random
MOBhp=100

def ATTACK(TYPEatck,MOBhp):
#    global MOBhp

    print ('the type attack chosen was ',TYPEatck,'the MOB has ',MOBhp)
    if TYPEatck =='M'or TYPEatck =='m':
        print ('the ',PLAYER,' used melee to attack',MOB)
        MOBhp=MOBhp-10
    elif TYPEatck =='R'or TYPEatck =='r':
        print ('the ',PLAYER,' used range to attack',MOB)
        MOBhp=MOBhp-5
    else:
        print ('please choose a valid attack')
    print ('the MOB hitpoints are ',MOBhp)
    return MOBhp;


PLAYER='HERO'
MOB='Dragon'
AC=12
while MOBhp > 0:
   TYPEatck=random.choice('RM')
   ATTACK(TYPEatck,MOBhp)
print('really the MOB hitpoints are ', MOBhp)        
print(MOB,'was slain by ',PLAYER)
```

This gives a repeating result that I have to break with cntrl+c

```
the type attack chosen was  R the MOB has  100
the  HERO  used range to attack Dragon
the MOB hitpoints are  95
the type attack chosen was  M the MOB has  100
the  HERO  used melee to attack Dragon
the MOB hitpoints are  90
the type attack chosen was  R the MOB has  100
the  HERO  used range to attack Dragon
the MOB hitpoints are  95
```

Where as if I do the following

```
enter code here
#while MOBhp > 0:
TYPEatck=random.choice('RM')
ATTACK(TYPEatck,MOBhp)
print('really the MOB hitpoints are ', MOBhp)        
print(MOB,'was slain by ',PLAYER)
```

I get the following results

```
the type attack chosen was  R the MOB has  100
the  HERO  used range to attack Dragon
the MOB hitpoints are  95
really the MOB hitpoints are  100
Dragon was slain by  HERO
```

I have tried to play with global variables as well and can't seem to get that to work either.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Python code is useless otherwise. As a guess, you don't seem to assign the return value of `ATTACK` back to `MOBhp`.

Comment: Also, you have incorrect spaces after some `print` statements, and no spaces before `or`

Answer (score 2):

As it is right now, you are throwing away the result of your calculation. You have to store it an use it as input for the next calculation.

```
while MOBhp > 0:
    TYPEatck=random.choice('RM')
    MOBhp = ATTACK(TYPEatck,MOBhp)
```

Answer (score 0):

MisterMiyagi's answer is helpful.
If you want to use global variables ,you may use it like this:

```
import random
MOBhp=100

def ATTACK(TYPEatck, hp):
    global MOBhp
    MOBhp = hp

    print('the type attack chosen was ',TYPEatck,'the MOB has ',MOBhp)
    if TYPEatck == 'M' or TYPEatck == 'm':
        print('the ',PLAYER,' used melee to attack',MOB)
        MOBhp = MOBhp - 10
        elif TYPEatck == 'R' or TYPEatck == 'r':
        print('the ',PLAYER,' used range to attack',MOB)
        MOBhp = MOBhp - 5
    else:
        print('please choose a valid attack')
    print('the MOB hitpoints are ',MOBhp)
    return MOBhp;


PLAYER = 'HERO'
MOB = 'Dragon'
AC = 12
while MOBhp > 0:
    TYPEatck = random.choice('RM')
    ATTACK(TYPEatck,MOBhp)

print('really the MOB hitpoints are ', MOBhp)        
print(MOB,'was slain by ',PLAYER)
```

Or,you can use class:

```
import random

class Game():
    def __init__(self, player, mob):
        self.player = player
        self.mob = mob
        self.mobhp = 100

    def ATTACK(self, TYPEatck):
        print('the type attack chosen was ',TYPEatck,'the MOB has ',self.mobhp)
        if TYPEatck == 'M' or TYPEatck == 'm':
            print('the ',self.player,' used melee to attack',self.mob)
            self.mobhp -= 10
        elif TYPEatck == 'R' or TYPEatck == 'r':
            print('the ',self.player,' used range to attack',self.mob)
            self.mobhp -= 5
        else:
            print('please choose a valid attack')
        print('the MOB hitpoints are ',self.mobhp)
        return self.mobhp;

    def get_MOBhp(self):
        return self.mobhp

PLAYER = 'HERO'
MOB = 'Dragon'
AC = 12
game = Game(PLAYER, MOB)
while game.get_MOBhp() > 0:
    TYPEatck = random.choice('RM')
    game.ATTACK(TYPEatck)

print('really the MOB hitpoints are ', game.get_MOBhp())        
print(MOB,'was slain by ',PLAYER)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for you assistance! I figured it out and was able to write my program to completion.

[Here is the code formatted and shared on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/578b6e/0300/)